# Is there a way to create cpu perfmon dashboard using WPF .net?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, performance

I have created it using winforms by just adding permon classes and downloading some realtime dasboards but i find it quite difficult in WPF

Comment: Well, you have to know WPF.  But yes, it's possible, and the result will probably be better than in Winforms.

Comment: It takes time to really learn wpf... but it can be fun.  Just gotta stay with it.

Comment: or atleast any hint , how i can use winforms controls in WPF ?so i will use perfmoncounter from toolbox

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [a lot of tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537844/12888024) that allows to draw various graphs in WPF.

But since i didn't find any manual graph drawing implementation, I've created the example - how to draw a graph in WPF using [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) programming pattern.

#### 0. Helper classes

For proper and easy MVVM implementation I will use 2 following classes.

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs** - to notify UI on changes.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs** - for easy commands use (for `Button`)

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

#### 1. Data implementation

As graph consists of contant amount of points an they're just turning around, I've implemented the Round-Robin Collection that has only one method `Push()`.

**RoundRobinCollection.cs**

```csharp
public class RoundRobinCollection : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<float> _values;
    public IReadOnlyList<float> Values => _values;

    public RoundRobinCollection(int amount)
    {
        _values = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            _values.Add(0F);
    }

    public void Push(float value)
    {
        _values.RemoveAt(0);
        _values.Add(value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));
    }
}
```

#### 2. Values collection to Polygon points Converter

Used in **View** markup

**PolygonConverter.cs**

```csahrp
public class PolygonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
        if (values.Length == 3 && values[0] is IReadOnlyList<float> dataPoints && values[1] is double width && values[2] is double height)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(0, height));
            points.Add(new Point(width, height));
            double step = width / (dataPoints.Count - 1);
            double position = width;
            for (int i = dataPoints.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(position, height - height * dataPoints[i] / 100));
                position -= step;
            }
        }
        return points;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

#### 3. View Model

The main class containing all business logic of the App

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _graphEnabled;
    private float _lastCpuValue;
    private ICommand _enableCommand;

    public RoundRobinCollection ProcessorTime { get; }

    public string ButtonText => GraphEnabled ? "Stop" : "Start";

    public bool GraphEnabled
    {
        get => _graphEnabled;
        set
        {
            if (value != _graphEnabled)
            {
                _graphEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonText));
                if (value)
                    ReadCpu();
            }
        }
    }

    public float LastCpuValue
    {
        get => _lastCpuValue;
        set
        {
            _lastCpuValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand EnableCommand => _enableCommand ?? (_enableCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        GraphEnabled = !GraphEnabled;
    }));

    private async void ReadCpu()
    {
        try
        {
            using (PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total"))
            {
                while (GraphEnabled)
                {
                    LastCpuValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
                    ProcessorTime.Push(LastCpuValue);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ProcessorTime = new RoundRobinCollection(100);
    }
}
```

***Disclamer:** `async void` is not recommended approach to make something `async` but here the usage is safe because any possible `Exception` will be handled inside. For more information about why `async void` is bad, refer to the documentation - [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).*

#### 4. View

The whole UI markup of the app

```xml
<Window x:Class="CpuUsageExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CpuUsageExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/><!-- attach View Model -->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PolygonConverter x:Key="PolygonConverter"/><!-- attach Converter -->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Margin="5" Padding="10,0" Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding EnableCommand}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="CPU:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0, 5" Text="{Binding LastCpuValue, StringFormat=##0.##}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0, 5" Text="%" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <Border Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
                <Polygon Stroke="CadetBlue" Fill="AliceBlue">
                    <Polygon.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Polygon">
                            <Setter Property="Points">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PolygonConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ProcessorTime.Values"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Polygon.Resources>
                </Polygon>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

**P.S.** There's no code-behind

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great help , Thank you so much for this :-)

Comment: I am trying to add x (CPU) and y(dates for atleast 3-4 intervals) co-rdinates in this graph however no luck !!!

Comment: @user8758891 You may draw the grid on underlying Canvas ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495171/12888024))

Comment: @user8758891 Adding text isn't a trivial job because you probably need to modify the RRC to store the timestamp of the each value. Then add some `ItemsControl` under the `Canvas` and bind it to the same RRC through another converter, or create some additional `ObservableCollection` what will contain coordinates for each `TextBlock` and text inside. Then modify the both collections as once.

Comment: @user8758891 did I answered the question? Did you check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537844/12888024) at the top of the answer? If the question was answered, please accept the answer. If not, I'll delete the answer as unhelpful because I have no more ideas.

Comment: Thanks I have accepted , It helps me thanks once again